# Template overlay using Sightly

Tags: aem

I am pretty new to AEM. I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/howto/website.html) from the official documentation. I already did it from top to bottom, but now I am trying to do it again but using Eclipse, Maven and Sightly instead of JSP.

I've been following until the step "Using your own scripts". As I am trying to use Sightly instead of JSP I've ended up with the following files:

**contentpage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <div data-sly-include="head.jsp" data-sly-unwrap></div>
    <div data-sly-include="body.jsp" data-sly-unwrap></div>
</html>
```

**body.jsp**

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
<%
%><body>
    <div id="CQ">
        <div class="topnav">topnav</div>
        <div class="content">
            <cq:include script="left.html" />
            <cq:include script="center.html" />
            <cq:include script="right.html" />
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="toolbar">toolbar</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**left.html**

```
<div class="left">
    <div>logo</div>
    <div>newslist</div>
    <div>search</div>
</div>
```

**center.html**

```
<div class="center">
    <div>trail</div>
    <div>title</div>
    <div>parsys</div>
</div>
```

**right.html**

```
<div class="right">
    <div>iparsys</div>
</div>
```

In addition, the node apps/myproject/components/contentpage has an attribute `sling:resourceSuperType="foundation/components/page"` so it is inheriting from the page component provided.

Everything works as expected, but as I said before, I am trying to use only Sightly, but at the moment I've got the file `body.jsp`, which I think I need it to be JSP so it has the same name as /libs/foundation/components/page/body.jsp.

Is there a way to get rid of the `body.jsp` and use a sightly script instead? I suspect that maybe there is a `components/page/body.html` somewhere, but no idea where to look for it (in case it really exists).

Thanks.

Comment: Why not inherit from `wcm/foundation/components/page` instead of `foundation/components/page`. The WCM foundation page is already on sightly?

Comment: Yes, I just found it out before reading your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by `rakhi4110`, and as I suspected, there is a sightly version of the page component. It is located in `wcm/foundation/components/page` so the only thing to do is inherit from it instead of `foundation/components/page`.

This is a link to an article that put me on track, in case is useful for somebody else: http://scottwestover.blogspot.co.uk/2015/04/aem-tutorial-on-building-sightly-page.html